# AWS Chatbot response sent to mobile as text message, which is not recognized as proper URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, amazon-lex

I wrote a Bot using AWS service. When a utterance said like "APPLY" i am populating a URL link as response. which will be sent to mobile as a plain text format. When I do this URL is being changed
example:- The URL https://dothework.com/index.action?**langId=EN&app=SOLUN**#ctn  is changed to https://dothework.com/index.action?**langId=EN&app=SOLUN**#ctn

How to resolve this "&" to "&" problem in the URL.

Comment: How to resolve the "&amp;" to  & in the URL.

Comment: example:- The URL https://dothework.com/index.action?langId=EN&app=SOLUN#ctn is changed to https://dothework.com/index.action?langId=EN&amp;app=SOLUN#ctn

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. we can use **custom response** option. It populates the message what ever we post in it.